# Pound Ubuntu 12.04.1 - Private IP in apache logs. Should be Client's external IP. Help?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, reverse-proxy, pound

Have installed apsis Pound on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.1.

I am forwarding HTTP requests to an XServe (Snow Leopard Server) Apache instance, my problem is that I am getting local private IP addresses in the access_log, and pretty much all logs on the backend.

Simple config snippet below:

```
ListenHTTP
    Address 192.168.1.100
    Port    80

    ## allow PUT and DELETE also (by default only GET, POST and HEAD)?:
    xHTTP   1

    #Virtual host www.mywebsite.com
    Service
        HeadRequire "Host:.*mywebsite.com.*"
        BackEnd
            Address 192.168.1.250
            Port    80
        End
    End
```

Now, should I be adding an X-Forwarded-For header in Pound? I thought Pound did this automatically.

Or perhaps, do I do a HeadRemove: X-Forwarded-For on incoming requests first? This might be confusing issues.

Would love it if anyone could get back to me!

Cheers,

James

Comment: So what is the actual problem? That in your access_log on your apache server you are getting the IP of the Ubuntu server (192.168.1.100)?

Comment: Exactly, boburob.

Basically, it will become much more difficult to marry together information from the pound log (in ubuntu syslog) with the OSX apache access_log if I am relying on timestamps. 

This way I can do scripts for page hits, unique IPs etc, without grepping through the ubuntu syslog first.

Is it a Pound config change or an OSX Apache config change (if so through terminal or the GUI?) to get Client IP addresses in OSX logs?